# Event Listener not working in cookie modal

Tags: javascript, cookies, modal-dialog, addeventlistener

first time caller here, please be gentle..

I am in the process of my JavaScript reflection and having a problem with the cookie modal. You need to be able to have the cookie pop up upon entering the site, the user needs to click ok, it is stored locally, and doesn't pop up if the user refreshes the browser.

I have created a basic modal and written the JavaScript, which partly works, but the eventHandler isn't working.

The cookie value is false, which you can see in the console, but when you click the button, it doesn't turn to true.

I have put the code below and if anyone could help I'd really appreciate it.

```
<div id ="overlay">
    <div class="modal">
      <p>
      </p>
    </div>
        <button class="settings_button">CHANGE SETTINGS</button>
        <button class="modal_accept_button">ACCEPT COOKIES</button>
            <button class="modal_accept_button">Accept</button>
 </div>

    
let modalObject = document.querySelector(".modal");
let modalSettings = document.querySelector('.settings_button');
let modalAccept = document.querySelector('.modal_accept_button');
let modalOverlay = document.querySelector("#overlay");

function showModal() {
  modalObject.classList.remove('deactive');
  modalOverlay.classList.remove('deactive');
}

function disableModal() {
  modalObject.classList.add('deactive');
  modalOverlay.classList.add('deactive');
}

localStorage.setItem('cookie', 'false');

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
     if (localStorage.getItem('cookie') == 'true') {
       console.log("Cookie is already in place.");
     } else if (localStorage.getItem('cookie') === null ||
     localStorage.getItem("Cookie accepted") == 'false') {
      console.log("Cookie has been not yet been accepted.");
      showModal();
      modalAccept.addEventListener('click', () => {
          localStorage.setItem('cookie','true');
          disableModal() ;
       });
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have a line that sets it to false:

```
localStorage.setItem('cookie', 'false');
```

This will *always* set it to false every time you go to that page. So even if you set it to true, when you refresh it will be back to false again.

Removing that line should work, as you dont need to set it to false

Comment: Thank you for your reply, that line is for testing, even when i comment it out or remove it completely the state doesn't change to true. If any more details are needed please let me know.

Comment: What do you get when you do `console.log(localStorage.getItem('cookie'))` in the `DOMContentLoaded`? Does it have any value at all?

Answer (score 0):

You have `localStorage.setItem('cookie', 'false');` in your code and this changes your ls to false every time that your codes run, **just remove it** and I think it's better if you save your local storage in a variable then use that variable in your if statement:

```
const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
const acceptBtn = document.querySelector('#acceptCookies');


(() => {
 const isCookieAccepted = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('cookie'));
  
 if (isCookieAccepted) {
  alert(`Cookie status: ${isCookieAccepted}`)
 } else {
  modal.classList.add('show')
 }
})();

acceptBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
 window.localStorage.setItem('cookie', true);
 modal.classList.remove('show')
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, that line is for testing, even when i comment it out or remove it completely the state doesn't change to true. I changed the code to match yours and it still doesn't work, I am not sure if maybe I have missed something out that would explain the situation more clearly. If any more details are needed please let me know.

Comment: I create an example for in this link: https://jsfiddle.net/z382edhk/1/ @lloydcox